# Finding the Number of Messages Sent for Every Person in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (message) AS 'Number Of Messages',
    person.id,
    first_name AS 'Sender\'s first name',
    last_name AS 'Sender\'s last name'
FROM person
JOIN message
    ON person.id = message.person_id;
```

This is the Question:

Task 14: Find the Number of Messages Sent for Every Person

Construct the SQL statement to find the number of messages sent for every person. Note: You must use the WHERE clause to set the conditions for this query. Display the following columns:

```
-Count of messages
-Person ID
-First Name
-Last Name
```

here are the tables we are working with

table name: message

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message                                   | send_datetime      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |        1 |          2 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!   | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |
|         2 |        2 |          1 | Congrats on winning 23 gold medals!       | 2016-12-25 09:01:00 |
|         3 |        3 |          1 | You're the greatest swimmer ever          | 2016-12-25 09:02:00 |
|         4 |        1 |          3 | Thanks! You're the greatest sprinter ever | 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |
|         5 |        1 |          4 | Good luck on your race                    | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

table name: person

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|        1 | Michael   | Phelps   |
|        2 | Katie     | Ledecky  |
|        3 | Usain     | Bolt     |
|        4 | Allyson   | Felix    |
|        5 | Kevin     | Durant   |
|        6 | Diana     | Taurasi  |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Can anyone show me where I've gone wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for all the help everyone! they don't work without errors but they definitely give me a great place to start and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `Number Of Messages`,
    p.id,
    p.first_name AS `Sender's first name`,
    p.last_name AS `Sender's last name`
FROM 
    person p inner JOIN 
    message m ON p.person_id = m.person_id
group by
    p.person_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name;
```

Result should look like

> Number Of Messages  id  Sender's first name  Sender's last name
>   3                                  1            Ivan                         Drago

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a left join from the `person` table to the `message` table which finds the counts for each person:

```
SELECT
    p.person_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name,
    COUNT(m.person_id) AS num_messages
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN message
    ON p.person_id = m.person_id
GROUP BY
    p.person_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name;
```

Note: We need a left join here, to cover the edge case of persons who have sent no messages.  In this case, we want to report zero for their count.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `Number Of Messages`,
    p.id,
    p.first_name AS `Sender's first name`,
    p.last_name AS `Sender's last name`
FROM 
    person p LEFT JOIN 
    message m ON p.person_id = m.person_id
group by
    p.person_id,
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be so tired that I'm staring at the person who gave the answer that help me get the right one. Sorry I cant remember but thank you!

This is what worked correctly:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(message.message_id) AS 'Count of messages',
person.person_id,
person.first_name AS 'First Name',
person.last_name AS 'Last Name'
FROM message
INNER JOIN person
ON message.sender_id = person.person_id
group by person.person_id,person.first_name,person.last_name;
```