# Find All of the Messages that Have At Least One Image Attached Using INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql

I don't know where to begin with this question. Can anyone one give me some examples or a skeleton of the the `SELECT` query for this question.

> Task 15: Find All of the Messages that Have At Least One Image
>   Attached Using `INNER JOIN`s
>
> Construct the SQL statement to find all of the messages that have at
>   least one image attached using `INNER JOIN`s.
>
> `Note`: For messages with multiple images, display only the first image
>   for the message. Display the following

**columns**:

```
-Message ID

-Message

-Message Timestamp

-First Image Name

-First Image Location
```

**Tables:**

table name: `image`

```
+------------+----------+

| message_id | image_id |

+------------+----------+

|         5 |       1 |

|         4 |       2 |

|         1 |       3 |

|         3 |       4 |

|         3 |       5 |

+------------+----------+
```

table name: `message`

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+

| message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message                                   | send_datetime      |

+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+

|         1 |        1 |          2 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!   | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |

|         2 |        2 |          1 | Congrats on winning 23 gold medals!       | 2016-12-25 09:01:00 |

|         3 |        3 |          1 | You're the greatest swimmer ever          | 2016-12-25 09:02:00 |

|         4 |        1 |          3 | Thanks! You're the greatest sprinter ever | 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |

|         5 |        1 |          4 | Good luck on your race                    | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |

+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Perhaps you should accept one of the answers in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349613/finding-the-number-of-messages-sent-for-every-person-in-mysql) before asking a new one.

Comment: And just maybe try to figure this out for yourself

Comment: I am working on both questions and am in the process of revising the answers that I was given on my first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: hope it will work

```
Select m.*, i.image_id from message m inner join image i on m.image_id = i.image_id where i.image_id != "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help but I got a really good answer from course hero with an awesome explanation of each component so I understand now. 
here is the code:

```
select m_i.message_id, min(m.message) as message, min(m.send_datetime)

as send_datetime, min(i.image_name) as First_Image_Name,

min(i.image_location) as First_Image_Location from

message m inner join message_image m_i on

m.message_id = m_i.message_id inner join

image i on i.image_id = m_i.image_id

group by m_i.message_id;
```

Shout out to Stuent_kunalsingh from course hero for this answer and the great explanation he provided over there.

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed and saw that you just posted that you got answer.
Funny enough.. I'm late on this assignment as well and I just finished this last task.

Here was my personal solution:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> m.message_id,
    -> m.message,
    -> m.send_datetime AS "message timestamp",
    -> i.image_name,
    -> i.image_location
    -> FROM message_image mi
    -> INNER JOIN message m ON m.message_id = mi.message_id
    -> INNER JOIN image i ON i.image_id = mi.image_id
    -> WHERE i.image_id != 3;

    +------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+------
    ----------------+----------------+
    | message_id | message                                 | message timestamp   | image
    _name           | image_location |
    +------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+------
    ----------------+----------------+
    |          1 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle! | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 | Winni
    ng Gold         | Athens in 2004 |
    |          2 | Congrats on winning 23 gold medals!     | 2016-12-25 09:01:00 | Team
    USA Basketball  | Athens in 2004 |
    |          3 | You're the greatest swimmer ever        | 2016-12-25 09:02:00 | Kevin
     Durant and OKC | Oklahoma City  |
    |          5 | Good luck on your race                  | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 | Micha
    el P            | Nightclub      |
    +------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+------
    ----------------+----------------+
    4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

For further explanation: My where statement is very important, because the task is to make sure to leave out the second image if a message as two images. My fifth message (`message_id = 5`) had two images so I used that `WHERE` statement to omit the second image. It really helps to select from all tables to show yourself what you're working with before attempting the task. As a Easter egg, in my case my tables looked something like this:

```
 message_image table
+------------+----------+
| message_id | image_id |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        1 |
|          2 |        4 |
|          3 |        5 |
|          5 |        2 |
|          5 |        3 |
+------------+----------+

                    image table
+----------+----------------------+----------------+
| image_id | image_name           | image_location |
+----------+----------------------+----------------+
|        1 | Winning Gold         | Athens in 2004 |
|        2 | Michael P            | Nightclub      |
|        3 | Roses                | France         |
|        4 | Team USA Basketball  | Athens in 2004 |
|        5 | Kevin Durant and OKC | Oklahoma City  |
+----------+----------------------+----------------+

                                  message table
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------
+---------------------+
| message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message
| send_datetime       |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------
+---------------------+
|          1 |         1 |           2 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!
| 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |
|          2 |         2 |           1 | Congrats on winning 23 gold medals!
| 2016-12-25 09:01:00 |
|          3 |         3 |           1 | You're the greatest swimmer ever
| 2016-12-25 09:02:00 |
|          4 |         1 |           3 | Thanks!  You're the greatest sprinter ever
| 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |
|          5 |         1 |           4 | Good luck on your race
| 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------
+---------------------+
```

As you can see from the `message_image` table the fifth message had images two and three which was Michael Phelps sending Allyson Felix pictures of himself at the Nightclub and of Roses. Naturally I had to omit the second picture which (`image_id = 3`) because the assignment told me to omit the second image, and I don't want Michael Phelps to have to experience heartbreak if Felix doesn't reciprocate his feelings.